# Use the same channel for mobile and web applications

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I'm developing a flutter mobile app with Agora IO. Would like to know if it is possible that a mobile and a web user could share the same channel using the platform...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use same channel on web and on mobile iOS/Android.

You might want to configure the codec used according to this doc https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/web_on_mobile

Comment: Nice! Thnak you for your time!!